# Storing data through into Realm through Retrofit

Tags: android, realm, retrofit

I am developing Android app I want to save Retrofit JSON response into RealmDatabase but I cannot call getIntroduction method on response.body 
I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835605/store-data-into-realm-through-retrofit-2)

> below my IntroductionItem.java

public class IntroductionItem extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public List<Introduction> introductionList;
public IntroductionAdapter adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.introduction);
    KitabInterface kitabInterface = ApiClient.getApiService();
    Call<KitabSawti> call = kitabInterface.getIntroduction();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<RealmList<KitabSawti>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RealmList<KitabSawti>> call, Response<RealmList<KitabSawti>> response) {
            introductionList =  response.body().getIntroduction;
            Realm.init(IntroductionItem.this);

            RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                    .name("overview.realm")
                    .schemaVersion(1)
                    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                    .build();
            Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);


            // add response to realm database
            Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
            realm.beginTransaction();
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(resource);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.close();
```

// programmatically check : data is inserted in to realm or not

```
            int notesCount = realm.where(KitabSawti.class).findAll().size();
            int notesCount2 = realm.where(Introduction.class).findAll().size();


            Log.d("my first",String.valueOf(notesCount));
            Log.d("my second",String.valueOf(notesCount2));





            RecyclerView recyclerView  =  findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
            adapter = new IntroductionAdapter(IntroductionItem.this,introductionList); // changes
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RealmList<KitabSawti>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

> Pojo class: KitabSawti

public class KitabSawti extends RealmObject {

```
@SerializedName("Introduction")
@Expose
private RealmList<Introduction> introduction = null;
@SerializedName("Education")
@Expose
private List<Education> education = null;
@SerializedName("Work")
@Expose
private List<Work> work = null;
@SerializedName("Skills")
@Expose
private List<Skill> skills = null;
@SerializedName("Contact")
@Expose
private List<Contact> contact = null;

public RealmList<Introduction> getIntroduction() {
    return introduction;
}

public void setIntroduction(RealmList<Introduction> introduction) {
    this.introduction = introduction;
}

public List<Education> getEducation() {
    return education;
}

public void setEducation(List<Education> education) {
    this.education = education;
}

public List<Work> getWork() {
    return work;
}

public void setWork(List<Work> work) {
    this.work = work;
}

public List<Skill> getSkills() {
    return skills;
}

public void setSkills(List<Skill> skills) {
    this.skills = skills;
}

public List<Contact> getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(List<Contact> contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}
```

}

> Introduction.java

public class Introduction  extends RealmObject {

```
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;
@SerializedName("introduction")
@Expose
private String introduction;

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getIntroduction() {
    return introduction;
}

public void setIntroduction(String introduction) {
    this.introduction = introduction;
}
```

}

below screenshot error where I am getting
[image: error]

> below my ApiClient

public class ApiClient

```
{


        public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.mocky.io/";

        /**
         * Get Retrofit Instance
         */


        public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

            return new Retrofit.Builder()

                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

        }

        /**
         * Get API Service
         *
         * @return API Service
         */
        public static KitabInterface getApiService() {
            return getRetrofitInstance().create(KitabInterface.class);
        }
    }
```

below Interface

```
public interface KitabInterface {

    @GET("v2/5bd2e8ec3400006f00cfdf42")
    Call<KitabSawti> getIntroduction();
    @GET("v2/5bd2e8ec3400006f00cfdf42")
    Call<KitabSawti> getEducation();
    @GET("v2/5bd2e8ec3400006f00cfdf42")
    Call<KitabSawti> getWork();
    @GET("v2/5bd2e8ec3400006f00cfdf42")
    Call<KitabSawti> getSkills();
    @GET("v2/5bd2e8ec3400006f00cfdf42")
    Call<KitabSawti> getContact();





}
```

Comment: What is the error and in which line rises?

Comment: @Juanje Thanks for your response I have post screenshot error where I am getting error in this line  introductionList =  response.body().getIntroduction();

Comment: I think the problem is in the Response conversion. Check the Gson converter in Retrofit instatiation. Btw, you could split this operation in order to get simpler steps instead of returning the final RealmList.

Comment: @Juanje,Can you be more specific I did not understand

Comment: You are trying to return a `Response<RealmList<KitabSawti>> response`. This means that the you are using the Gson converter in the Retrofit initialization to make this conversion by default. I don't know if it is too much for the converter. Try to return the response as ArrayList or a raw JSON and then make the conversions in this method.